# Certain pictures render in weird green and purple palette in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, photos, color-profiles

I'm running Mint 19.1 on my laptop, and I don't know what changed, but sometimes images will just have this weird color palette.

On Firefox, it happens on some websites, but not others. Facebook is really bad about it, almost everything there is messed up. On Twitter, it only does it to the profile pictures.

It happens consistently with the Mint image viewer, but not at all with the desktop. Also, when I open a screenshot of a messed-up image in the image viewer, it sets it back to normal.

Some examples:

[image: Number One]

[image: Number Two]

And here's what it looks like when I open the messed-up screenshot in the image viewer:

[image: Number Three]

Comment: Check the image file itself. Might be a longshot, but sometimes when an image is saved as CMYK and then displayed in RGB that kind of color palette appears.

Comment: This isn't limited to just one image, though. All these pictures will render fine in GIMP, but be messed up elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly Images with a built-in color profile that isn't taken in accout properly. In Gimp use `Image>Image properties` and the `Color profile` tab to check this.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone googling with the same problem, I finally figured it out. I went to

> Start menu -> Preferences -> Color

and I noticed there was a color profile that said "Swapped Red and Green".
Removed it, and everything's fine.